# How can we trigger data point click event in lineseries chart using WinRT XAML Toolkit for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I've created line series chart application for windows phone 8.1.
Code is here-

```
<Charting:LineSeries Title="Rating" Margin="0" IndependentValuePath="Name" DependentValuePath="Amount" IsSelectionEnabled="True"  >
</Charting:LineSeries >
```

Here is Output -

[image]

In desktop application(wpf) datapoint detail shown while mousehover on them but In windows phone there is no event like desktop(wpf)

I want to get datapoint details while clicking on them.

How can I get this on data point click?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to copy your mouseover events to Tapped events. Inside Tapped events you can write do a check by encasing code in `#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP` block if you want it to work only for Phone.
There is also an option of defining `<ToolTipService.ToolTip >` template inside your control but as per user experience it wont give satisfactory result.

Comment: Whats not working is tap event not being recognized. Are you passing correct arguments. Which part is not working maybe I can help